# Use ember-simple-validaiton to validate property on hasMany relation

Tags: ember.js

this question is about particular plugin - ember-cli-simple-validation.

Lets assume that there is two models

```
User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
  emails: DS.hasMany('email')
})

Email = DS.Model.extend({
  address: DS.attr()
  emails: DS.belongsTo('user')
})
```

and user dynamically create emails:

```
<button {{action 'createEmail'}}>Add Email</button>
{{#each model.emails as |email index|}}
  {{input value=email.address}}
{{/each}}
```

is it possible to use ember-simple-validaiton in this situation to validate presence of address on each of the emails?

I tried to go with `validateEach` but getting an `Error while processing route: profile self.get(...).forEach is not a function TypeError: self.get(...).forEach is not a function` error on the https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-validation/blob/master/addon/mixins/validate.js#L66

controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {ValidationMixin, validateEach} from "ember-cli-simple-validation/mixins/validate";

var isLegit = function(address) {
    return address && address.length > 3;
};

export default Ember.Controller.extend(ValidationMixin, {
  emailAddressValidation: validateEach("model.emails", isLegit),
  actions: {
    createChildren: function(type) {
      this.store.createRecord(type, {profile: this.get('model')});
    },
});
```

template:

```
{{#each model.emails as |email index|}}
  {{input value=email.address}}
  {{#validation-error-field submitted=submitted field="address" model=mode.emails index=index validation="basic"}}invalid address{{/validation-error-field}}
{{/each}}
```

model:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend{

  address: DS.attr(''),
  kind: DS.attr(''),
  contactable: DS.belongsTo('contactable', { polymorphic: true, inverse: 'emails', async: false }),

  kindIsPrimed: false,
  kindChanged: Ember.observer('kind', function () {
    this.set('kindIsPrimed', true);
  }),

  addressIsPrimed: false,
  addressChanged: Ember.observer('address', function () {
    this.set('addressIsPrimed', true);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the surface (without running the code) you might alter your hbs from this

```
{{#each model.emails as |email index|}}
  {{input value=email.address}}
  {{#validation-error-field submitted=submitted field="address" model=mode.emails index=index validation="basic"}}invalid address{{/validation-error-field}}
{{/each}}
```

to instead ...

```
{{#each model.emails as |email index|}}
  {{input value=email.address}}
  {{#validation-error-field submitted=submitted field="address" model=email index=index validation="basic"}}invalid address{{/validation-error-field}}
{{/each}}
```

In the validateEach scenario (for array validation) you need to set the model and index on each iteration. The model should still be the individual model (not the array itself).

Another example that's tested in the addon for reference

https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-validation/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/templates/many.hbs